# How to fix improperly distributed lighting projected onto a model in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, lighting

I've been trying to implement the Blinn-Phong lighting model to project lighting onto an imported Wavefront OBJ model through Assimp([github link](https://github.com/assimp/assimp)).

The model seems to be loaded correctly, however, there seems to be a point where the lighting appears to be "cut off" near the middle of the model.

Image of the imported model with and without lighting enabled.
[image]

As you can see on the left of the image above, there is a region in the middle of the model where the light effectively gets "split up" which is not what is intended. It can be seen that there is a sort of discrepancy where the side facing towards the light source appears brighter than normal and the side away from the light source appears darker than normal without any sort of easing in between the two sides.

I believe there might be something wrong with how I've implemented the lighting model in the fragment shader but I cannot say for sure as to why this is happening.

---

*Vertex shader:*

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vertTexCoords;

out vec3 fragPos;
out vec3 fragNormal;
out vec2 fragTexCoords;

uniform mat4 proj, view, model;
uniform mat3 normalMat;

void main() {
    fragPos = vec3(model * vec4(vertPos, 1));
    gl_Position = proj * view * vec4(fragPos, 1);
    fragTexCoords = vertTexCoords;
    fragNormal = normalMat * vertNormal;
}
```

*Fragment shader:*

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 fragPos;
in vec3 fragNormal;
in vec2 fragTexCoords;

out vec4 FragColor;

const int noOfDiffuseMaps = 1;
const int noOfSpecularMaps = 1;

struct Material {
    sampler2D diffuseMaps[noOfDiffuseMaps], specularMaps[noOfSpecularMaps];
    float shininess;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 ambient, diffuse, specular;
};

uniform Material material;
uniform Light light;

uniform vec3 viewPos;

const float pi = 3.14159265;

uniform float gamma = 2.2;

float near = 0.1;
float far = 100;
  
float LinearizeDepth(float depth) 
{
    float z = depth * 2 - 1;
    return (2 * near * far) / (far + near - z * (far - near));  
}

void main() {
    vec3 normal = normalize(fragNormal);

    vec3 calculatedColor = vec3(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfDiffuseMaps; i++) {
        vec3 diffuseTexel = texture(material.diffuseMaps[i], fragTexCoords).rgb;

        // Ambient lighting
        vec3 ambient = diffuseTexel * light.ambient;
    
        // Diffuse lighting
        float diff = max(dot(light.direction, normal), 0);
        vec3 diffuse = diffuseTexel * light.diffuse * diff;

        calculatedColor += ambient + diffuse;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfSpecularMaps; i++) {
        vec3 specularTexel = texture(material.specularMaps[0], fragTexCoords).rgb;
        vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - fragPos);
        vec3 halfWayDir = normalize(viewDir + light.direction);
        float energyConservation = (8 + material.shininess) / (8 * pi);

        // Specular lighting
        float spec = pow(max(dot(halfWayDir, normal), 0), material.shininess);
        vec3 specular = specularTexel * light.specular * spec * energyConservation;

        calculatedColor += specular;
    }

    float depthColor = 1 - LinearizeDepth(gl_FragCoord.z) / far;
    FragColor = vec4(pow(calculatedColor, vec3(1 / gamma)) * depthColor, 1);
}
```

Comment: Inconsistent normals for vertexes along the join between two triangle strip/fan/meshes in your model?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your texture and colors are also linear(it is a simple pow 2.2) because you are doing gamma encoding at the end.

Also note, it is expected to have a harsh terminator.

[image: real life]

http://filmicworlds.com/blog/linear-space-lighting-i-e-gamma/

Beyond that, if you expect soft falloffs, it must be coming from an area light. For that you can implement wrap lighting or area lights.